# Installing and Running MongoDB on OSX

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, shell, database

If someone can provide some insights here I would GREATLY appreciate it.

I had a express/node.js app running on MongoDB locally successfully, but upon restarting my computer, I attempted to restart the Mongo server and it began giving errors and wouldn't start. Since then, I have re-installed Mongo several times only to find the same error occurring. this is what I am receiving:

```
privee:mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.6 jonlinton$ ./bin/mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Mon Aug 26 14:48:47.168 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at     src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Am I missing a step? Should I be creating a config file?

Comment: You need to run your Mongo Server, not Mongo Shell, this is the error of Mongo Shell that only says server is not running. Try to run server, and paste the error here.

Comment: I just ran `./bin/mongod` and it worked. So, to re-iterate, `./bin/mongod` starts the server? How do I start the shell?

Comment: `mongod` == the database server, `mongo` == interactive shell

Comment: This (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) actually covers setup and using the shell.

Comment: Note: Usually in unix the name of daemons (or services) end with a d (crond, ftpd, mysqld, etc...).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Assuming you have created the data/db directory under bin after install.

1. Start a terminal for your mongo server
2. Go to `<mongodb-install-directory>/bin` directory
3. Run the command

   ./mongod
4. Start a terminal for your mongo shell
5. Go to `<mongodb-install-directory>/bin` directory
6. Run the command (make sure you put the name of the database)

   ./mongo test

Comment: where is the mongo/bin directory?

Comment: @elliotrock __which mongod__ should give you the location

Comment: Use `./mongod -f ~/path/to/mongod.conf` since MongoDB does not use a configuration file unless you tell it to.

Comment: Use this(/usr/local/mongodb) path @elliotrock

Answer (score 194):

If you have installed mongodb through `homebrew` then you can simply start mongodb through (`mongodb-community` if installted `mongodb-community`

```
brew services start mongodb
```

OR

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Then access the shell by

```
mongo
```

You can shut down your db by

```
brew services stop mongodb
```

You can restart your db by

```
brew services restart mongodb
```

For more options

```
brew info mongodb
```

Answer (score 71):

**Updated answer (9/2/2019):**

Homebrew has removed mongodb formula from its core repository, see [this pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43770).

The new way to install mongodb using Homebrew is as follows:

```
~> brew tap mongodb/brew
~> brew install mongodb-community
```

After installation you can start the mongodb service by following the caveats:

```
~> brew info mongodb-community
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community: stable 4.2.0
High-performance, schema-free, document-oriented database
https://www.mongodb.com/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew/blob/master/Formula/mongodb-community.rb
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community now and restart at login:
  brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

**<del>Deprecated answer (8/27/2019):</del>**

<del>I assume you are using Homebrew. You can see the additional information that you need using `brew info $FORMULA`</del>

```
~> brew info mongo                                                           255
mongodb: stable 2.4.6, devel 2.5.1
http://www.mongodb.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.5-x86_64 (20 files, 287M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb
==> Caveats
To reload mongodb after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

<del>Caveats is what you need to follow after installation.</del>

Answer (score 24):

Problem here is you are trying to open a mongo shell without starting a mongo db which is listening to port 127.0.0.1:27017(deafault for mongo db) thats what the error is all about:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145 exception: connect failed
```

The easiest solution is to open the terminal and type

```
$ mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

Note: dbpath here is "Users/user" where data/db directories are created

i.e., you need to create directory **data** and sub directory **db** in your user folder.
For e.g say `

> **/Users/johnny/data**

After mongo db is up. Open another terminal in new window and type

```
$ mongo
```

it will open mongo shell with your mongo db connection opened in another terminal.

Answer (score 8):

## Mac Installation:

1. Install brew

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. Update and verify you are good with

   ```
   brew update
   brew doctor
   ```
3. Install mongodb with

   ```
   brew install mongodb
   ```
4. Create folder for mongo data files:

   ```
   mkdir -p /data/db
   ```
5. Set permissions

   ```
   sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
   ```
6. Open another terminal window & run and keep running a mongo server/daemon

   ```
   mongod
   ```
7. Return to previous terminal and run a mongodb shell to access data

   ```
   mongo
   ```

## To quit each of these later:

1. The Shell:

   ```
   quit()
   ```
2. The Server

   ```
   ctrl-c
   ```

Answer (score 8):

For those that could be facing the same problem and the solutions suggested above aren't working, for example in my case, I had installed mongodb-community, so you might wanna run the command below to restart your mongo server.

For those that installed mongodb-community using brew

`brew services start mongodb-community`

Answer (score 5):

additionally you may want mongo to run on another port, then paste this command on terminal,

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db/ --port 27018
```

where **27018** is the port we want mongo to run on

#### assumptions

1. mongod exists in your bin i.e `/usr/local/bin/` for mac ( which would be if you installed with brew), otherwise you'd need to navigate to the path where mongo is installed
2. the folder `/data/db/` exists

Answer (score 4):

```
mongo => mongo-db console
mongodb => mongo-db server
```

If you're on Mac and looking for a easier way to start/stop your mongo-db server, then [MongoDB Preference Pane](http://blog.codonomics.com/2014/08/start-stop-mongodb-server-in-mac.html) is something that you should look into. With it, you start/stop your mongo-db instance via UI. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are logged in as root user in your terminal.

Steps to start mongodb server in your mac

1. Open Terminal
2. Run the command `sudo su`
3. Enter your administrator password
4. run the command `mongod`
5. MongoDb Server starts

Hope it helps you.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**What worked for me on MacOS 12.6.1:**

1. Go to Homebrew copy the "Install Brew" link from there, paste and run.
   To check the version of brew

```
brew -v
```

then

```
brew tap mongodb/brew 
brew install mongodb-community 
sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db 
sudo chown -R `id -un` /System/Volumes/Data/data/db 
sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

this would run your MongoDB .

Then open another tab on terminal(command + t), and type

```
mongosh
```

This will definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing less likely to be outdated that the official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

Following answer is only to show  people how to run MongoDB Shell.
Following helped me to start the shell successfully.

- First start the service by using following command

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

- Now use the following command to start the shell in the terminal itself.

```
mongosh
```

- Dont forget to close the service using the following command

```
brew services stop mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 0):

Download MongoDB and install it on your local machine.
Link https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/enterprise

Extract the file and put it on the desktop.
Create another folder where you want to store the data. I have created mongodb-data folder.
Then run the below command.

```
Desktop/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath=/Users/yourname/Desktop/mongodb-data/
```

Before the hyphen is the executable path of your mongoDB and after hyphen is your data store.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I have to do the following to install mongodb locally on mac os (Monterey)

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

and then

```
brew install mongodb-community
```