# connecting to test mongoDB is failed

Tags: mongodb

I am new in mongoDB

I have tried to install mongoDB on win 8 - 32 bit
I followed "The Definitive Guide To MongoDB 2010" by Apress.
I pasted the file in C drive root "mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6"
Then I created nested folder in C
data/db ,
As the book was mentioned.
After that I opened cmd :

```
cd C:\ mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6
cd bin\
```

up to here everything went well
then I tried to connect to mongo

but :

```
mongo
couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

occured.

Where is problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Link to article? Why didn't you just read the actual documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/ ?

Comment: have you actually started the mongod ?

Comment: try running mongod in bin\. instead of mongo.Please refer to the same question in [stack overflow.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452023/installing-and-running-mongodb-on-osx

Comment: Every database has a server and a client. You are starting the client without starting the server. Also, I suggest getting acquainted with the basics before asking simple questions in a Q&A website.

Answer (score 2):

First Thing is
**MongoDB is almost always run as a network server that clients can connect to and
perform operations on** so

1. create a folder **data** and in that **db** folder i.e., **c:\data\db**
2. First we need to start the server with the command **mongod.exe** avial in your bin folder
   like **`C:\mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6\bin\mongod.exe`**
3. Run the mongo.exe avail in the bin folder like **`C:\mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.6\bin\mongo.exe`**

> Know How to stop the **mongod.exe**
>   
>   from the client we need to issue these commands

- **use admin**
- **db.shutdownServer()**
  then automatically mongod will shut and you need to quit from client with exit command

HAVE A NICE DAY WITH MONGO

Answer (score 1):

The database itself is an executable called `mongod.exe` (mongoDB daemon). First you need to start this one. When it is running, you can use `mongo.exe` (mongoDB shell) to connect to it and issue commands.

For more information, read the article ["Install MongoDB on Windows" from the official manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the binary files from https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386

After installing above binary file please go to bin directory (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin  -> default installation directory) and run following command

> mongod.exe --journal --storageEngine=mmapv1  --dbpath c:\data\db

Note:make sure that you have already created the c:\data\db directory

Also if you need a GUI interface for mongodb, you can use [Mongobooster](https://mongobooster.com/downloads)