# connect failed mongo db on mac osx

Tags: macos, mongodb

i'm trying to learn mongo db on my mac.  I installed mondgo db using homebrew and it appeard successful.  I created the dir `/data/db`.  when I type `mongo` into the terminal I get:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server [a bunch of numbers] at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145 exception:connect failed
```

I looked at the following answer on SO:  [Installing and Running MongoDB on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452023/installing-and-running-mongodb-on-osx)

in the check answer it says:
    1) Start a terminal for your mongo server
    2)Go to mongo/bin directory

What does it mean to start a terminal for your server? does that mean just open up a new terminal window?

Where can I find the mongo/bin directory?

Any other suggestions on getting mondoDB up and running would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should read the documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
And follow the instructions.

In this case the [bunch of numbers] are the hostname/ip and port number that the binary `mongo` has tried to connect to. What it's telling you is that there is no `mongod` binary listening on the hostname and port that `mongo` is trying to connect to.

You will need to start `mongod` before you are able to connect to it with a `mongo` shell. The documentation above outlines this further.

If you use homebrew the mongodb binaries will automatically be put on your path which means you won't need to cd into another directory like mongo/bin.

Good luck.

Comment: This was a great answer to a broad question that ended up helping me. +1

Answer (score 9):

Probably you run the mongodb first time. Based on the documentation you must follow a few steps and then you are ready to go.

First, create main db directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Make  sure that you have a read and write permission on that directory:

```
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

And to listen to default port, run:

```
mongod
```

Finally keep in mind that after the run "mongod" command do not close console tab. Open a new tab (Cmd + T) and run other commands on the new window. To close the mongod session simply hit the Ctrl + C on the previous tab.

Comment: Absolutely this helped me. Thanks a lot. I missed to create this directory before running mongo for the first time.

Comment: searched for hours, and finally this worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

when everything mentioned above did not work. I did the following thing (in Mac)

```
cd ~
mkdir -p data/db
```

After creating directory in home(which will be definitely allowed) most imp command is below

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db &
```

So that it could take the path of db which was in home directory (as we are not able to create in / dir. 
To avoid it running frequently, put the above command in .bash_profile file in home directory so that it will automatically run the above command whenever we try to use terminal in Mac

Note: Whenever we open the terminal it will execute the above command so that we can access the mongodb (I understand this should be taken place in background but it works fine) 
We need to press enter/return key to get the regular command line terminal and continue doing our work

Answer (score 2):

These steps worked for me well on Mac, you can give a shot, make sure you install brew first and put these lines in terminal line by line:

```
brew update
brew install mongodb
brew install mongodb --with-openssl
brew install mongodb --devel
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown -R [your username] /data/db
(Replace with your username with what you can get by typing whoami in the terminal)
mongod
```

Run you app, for example  **localhost:8000**